# What is a round trip problem? and why using Unstable functions could cause it? (unstableMakeIsData)

Tags: plutus-pioneer-program

Lecture 2 of plutus-pioneer-program, introduces **unstableMakeIsData**

In the lecture it is advised to use the **Stable** version in production.

Lars explains that the **Unstable** version does not make any guarantee that different constructor numbers will be preserved for future versions of Plutus. He further adds that:

> *A newer version of plutus does it in a different way it would be incompatible and you would have **round trip problems*** (??)

I understand the incompatibility issue, sure, but **what exactly is a round trip problem** in this context?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The round trip problem in programming is when you have 2 conversions functions (for example toJSON and fromJSON) that should be each others inverse but aren't. So you start with a value, then convert it but when you convert it back you don't get the value again.

So in this case: say you have created this datatype:

```
data MyType = Yes | No

unstableMakeIsData ''MyType
```

Then you convert the value `Yes` to a value of type `Data` using `toBuiltinData`:

```
yesAsData :: Data
yesAsData = toBuiltinData Yes
```

Later with a future version of Plutus you convert `yesAsData` back to a value of type `MyType` with `fromBuiltinData yesAsData` and you might get back `No` instead!

Comment: Well explained, thank you very much!